# Store raster names& means for a large n of rasters

Tags: loops, for-loop, raster

For a very large number of rasters, I need to loop over the rasters and have the raster name and mean cell value of the raster.

This code works correct but only stores the result of the last element in the loop and of course I need to store it for each i (=for each raster).

```
 for(i in ras){
      dfff$A <- cellStats(i,"mean")
      dfff$B <- i 
    }
```

What I need is a code that stores the result for each raster, both name and mean (so it's possible to see easily which mean corresponds to which raster). 
This codes errors fatally.

```
   for(i in ras){
      dfff[i]$A <- cellStats(i,"mean")
      dfff[i]$B <- i 
    }
```

Anyone any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If the rasters have the same origin and extent, you can simply do

```
library(raster)
s <- stack(ras)
cellStats(s)
```

Otherwise, you can do cellStats in a loop

```
d <- rep(NA, length(ras))
nms <- rep(NA, length(ras))
for(i in 1:length(ras)){
     d[i] <- cellStats(ras[[i]], "mean")
     nms[i] <- names(ras[[i]])
}
```

I am not sure what you mean with the "name" of the raster. In your code, you assign the entire object to "B". But either way, you do not need to do that in the loop, as you already have a list of rasters (I assume that is what `ras` is.) So you can also do

```
nms <- sapply(ras, names)
```

Or do you mean filename?

```
nms <- sapply(ras, filename)
```

Now you can do

```
df <- data.frame(name=nms, mean=d)
```

The problem with your second loop is that `i` is not a numeric index, it is a raster object. So you cannot do `diff[i]`

Comment: When I have a list of mean values , I need to see from which raster they originate. for example :raster "blue" has a mean of 3.39, raster "red" has a mean of 5.00, raster "apple" has a mean of 12.33, ... ;;  Ras is indeed a list of rasters

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it generates an error "invalid subscript type S4"
     d[i] <- cellStats(d[[i]], "mean")

Comment: I think the error was due to a typo (d instead of ras)  that I have fixed. As for `blue` and `apple`: yes, that is what ` sapply(ras, names)` will get you.